# Microsoft.Graph - sending email returns "ODataErrors.ODataError"

Tags: c#, azure, email, azure-active-directory

When sending out an email via Microsoft.Graph, I receive the "ODataErrors.ODataError" error. I **assume** something is missing in my AD setup, but I checked all the culprits: tenant ID, API permissions, etc.

Here is the code:

```
    public async Task<string> SendEmail()
    {
        string tenantId = "0XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX3";
        string clientId = "cXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXb";
        string objectId = "4XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXa";

        string clientSecret = "tXXXX~XXXX~XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXR";

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };
        var creds = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(creds, scopes );

        var message = new Message()
        {
            Subject = "My subject",
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                Content = "My content"
            },
            ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
            {
                new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "My@Email.com"
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var body = new SendMailPostRequestBody();
        body.Message = message;
        body.SaveToSentItems = false;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        try
        {
            await graphClient.Users[objectId].SendMail.PostAsync(body);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

With Panagiotis help, I was able to fix some embarrassing errors, but here I am stuck again.

**UPDATE:**

So I now removed every reference and every NuGet package from the solution and added them all one by one. Took several hours, but I still have the same situation.

Without specifying TLS1.2 I get a 426 error.

With TLS1.2 I receive the "ODataErrors.ODataError" error.

Visual Studio 2019.
All projects are .NET Framework 4.7.2.

**UPDATE 2:**

I created a new blank project targeting .NET 7.0 under Visual Studio 2022. Now I do not have to explicitly specify the TLS version, but still get the following error:

> Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Exception of type
> 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.    at
> Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.ThrowIfFailedResponse(HttpResponseMessage
> response, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, Activity activityForAttributes)   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendNoContentAsync(RequestInformation requestInfo, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendNoContentAsync(RequestInformation
> requestInfo, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailRequestBuilder.PostAsync(SendMailPostRequestBody body, Action`1 requestConfiguration, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at ConsoleApp.GraphHelper.SendEmail() in
> C:\ConsoleApp\ConsoleApp\GraphHelper.cs:line 53

Comment: Where's the exception thrown? Are you *sure* the variables you use aren't NULL? `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` is a bug by the way, which *prevents* .NET from using TLS1.3 even if it's available. All supported .NET versions use the best available TLS version automatically

Comment: `async void SendEmail()` is another bug because such methods can't be awaited. It should be async Task` instead and the call *must* be awaited. If the call isn't awaited, the caller will resume execution at the first `await` and probably exit before `SendEmail` had a chance to complete. Any objects you try to use may already be disposed or cleared

Comment: And even worse, `var sendMailRequest = graphClient.Users[objectId].SendMail.PostAsync(body);` never awaits for `PostAsync` to complete.

Comment: Without the line ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12, I get a 426 error, so I had it included.

Comment: That means there are more bugs - an obsolete .NET Framework or Windows version that don't support TLS 1.2 automatically. All *supported* ones do. The oldest supported version is 4.6.2

Comment: @LukeWage Could you try using **try-catch** method in your code to know the exact OData error by including code from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1191326/error-when-trying-to-read-custom-seccurity-attribu#:~:text=Copy-,using%20Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors%3B,-try%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20result)

Comment: @Sridevi See my edits in the question.

Comment: Can you post your settings in Azure?I am almost certain that there is something wrong with my setup.. Getting the same error in 3 different projects...

Answer (score 0):

I registered one **single-tenant** Azure AD application and granted **`Mail.Send`** API permission:

[image]

I created a new project targeting .NET 6.0 under Visual Studio 2022 and ran below code including **try-catch** method to get exact OData error:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appID";
var tenantId = "tenantID";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody
{
    Message = new Message
    {
        Subject = "Send mail - Demo purpose",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Html,
            Content = "Hi! This is Sri",
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "sridevixxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.com",
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
try
{
    await graphClient.Users["demouser@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent mail");
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

In my case, I got below error as the **demouser** does not have active Office 365 license assigned:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I tried to send the mail from user having active Office 365 license:

[image]

When I ran the code again by changing user, I got **response** successfully:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appID";
var tenantId = "tenantID";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody
{
    Message = new Message
    {
        Subject = "Send mail - Demo purpose",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Html,
            Content = "Hi! This is Sri",
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "sridevixxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com",
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
try
{
    await graphClient.Users["xxxxx_rk@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent mail");
}
catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked **`Sent items`** of that user where mail sent like this:

[image]

In your case, include **try-catch** block in your code as I mentioned and check what exact error you are getting. Feel free to comment if you are getting error different from mine.