# Azure AD Exception Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid

Tags: .net, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I create azure ad multi tenant application to allow organization and public emails.
Currently testing on .net console application.

```
 var tenantId = "d0748657 ........";
 var clientId = "23a9c7a6 ........";
 var authorityUri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";     
 var redirectUri = "http://localhost";

 var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
          .Create(clientId)
          .WithAuthority(new Uri(authorityUri))
          .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
          .Build();
```

Now when it comes to smtpScope, i am using https://outlook.office365.com/SMTP.Send

```
 var smtpScope = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/SMTP.Send",  }; 
            var accounts = await pca.GetAccountsAsync();
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            if (accounts.Any())          
                result = await pca.AcquireTokenSilent(smtpScope, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
            
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    result = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(smtpScope).ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (MsalException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Token : {result.AccessToken}");
```

When i sign in using my organization email, i get the token and everythings work fine, but when i sign in with my personal outlook account, i get this error

Error acquiring access token: MSAL.Desktop.4.56.0.0.MsalServiceException:
ErrorCode: invalid_scope
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: The provided resource value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid

What am i missing here? is the smtpScope not correct ?

Comment: I got [same error](https://i.imgur.com/YlxEOnt.png) with **personal outlook** account. AFAIK, `SMTP.Send` permission is currently available only for work or school(organizational) accounts, not personal Microsoft accounts after Feb 2023. Check similar issue [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1168242/smtp-send-oauth-permission-not-working-for-consume)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your code in my environment, I too got the **same error** with personal Outlook account:

```cs
 var tenantId = "d0748657 ........";
 var clientId = "23a9c7a6 ........";
 var authorityUri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";     
 var redirectUri = "http://localhost";

 var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
          .Create(clientId)
          .WithAuthority(new Uri(authorityUri))
          .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
          .Build();

 var smtpScope = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/SMTP.Send",  }; 
            var accounts = await pca.GetAccountsAsync();
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            if (accounts.Any())          
                result = await pca.AcquireTokenSilent(smtpScope, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
            
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    result = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(smtpScope).ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (MsalException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Token : {result.AccessToken}");
```

**Response:**

[image]

> AFAIK, `SMTP.Send` permission is currently available only for **work** or **school**(organizational) accounts, not **personal** Microsoft accounts after Feb 2023 to generate OAuth2 access token.

When I ran the same code again with **organizational** account, I got token successfully in **response** like this:

[image]

To **confirm** that, I decoded the token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) where **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims are as below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can switch to **Microsoft Graph API** by adding `Mail.Send`to send mails from personal Outlook accounts. For that, modify your code by replacing **scope** value:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

var clientId = "appId";
var authorityUri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
var redirectUri = "http://localhost";

var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
         .Create(clientId)
         .WithAuthority(new Uri(authorityUri))
         .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
         .Build();

var graphScopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send" };

var accounts = await pca.GetAccountsAsync();
AuthenticationResult result = null;

if (accounts.Any())
{
    result = await pca.AcquireTokenSilent(graphScopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
}
else
{
    try
    {
        result = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(graphScopes).ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Token : {result.AccessToken}");
}
```

When I signed in with **personal** outlook account by running above code, I got consent prompt like this:

[image]

After accepting above consent, I got **access token** successfully in console like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[SMTP.Send OAuth permission not working for consumer accounts - Microsoft Q&A by **Akshay-MSFT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1168242/smtp-send-oauth-permission-not-working-for-consume)

Comment: Thank you very much, that is such great help . 
One more thing, i am using this code to send email 
 using (var emailClient = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(result.Account.Username, result.AccessToken);
                    await emailClient.ConnectAsync("smtp.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                    await emailClient.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);  
        // Send email

Comment: But Authenticate is throwing this error.
MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: '535: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [DX0P273CA0036.AREP273.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2023-10-05T09:20:17.090Z 08DBC5131D11B252]'

I guess its not compatible with
"https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send"

Comment: To send mail using Microsoft Graph, you need to modify your code by using `Microsoft.Graph` module. Refer these threads [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76225481/how-to-send-email-with-aad-graph-api-with-personal-outlook-account/76235164#76235164) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76727657/microsoft-graph-sending-email-returns-odataerrors-odataerror/76735150#76735150) if it helps!